# Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in ..../ma.php on line 8

Tags: php, telegram

i am using a simple php code found in some website which is used to send a message to telegram

i get this error how to solve it ?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in ..../ma.php on line 8
```

the original code:

```
    <?php
// Telegram function which you can call
function telegram($msg) {
        global $telegrambot,$telegramchatid;
        $url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$telegrambot.'/sendMessage';$data=array('chat_id'=>$telegramchatid,'text'=>$msg);
        $options=array('http'=>array('method'=>'POST','header'=>"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",'content'=>http_build_query($data),),);
        $context=stream_context_create($options);
        $result=file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
        return $result;
}

// Set your Bot ID and Chat ID.
$telegrambot='7345345735:agADFsfjdfhSGTYJdfafhksdsdrQ';
$telegramchatid=374659345;

// Function call with your own text or variable
telegram ("Here is your message!!");
?>
```

Comment: "Network is unreachable" suggests a firewall is blocking you.

Comment: so can i solve it ??? (it`s kinda free host :))

Comment: Free hosting services often block these kinds of things, to prevent being used to DoS other sites. You may have to use a pay service.

Comment: so the code has no problems right ?

Comment: Right, it looks similar to the code I found on their website.